# Run gradle test tasks in docker from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: docker, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm working on [a project](https://github.com/oss-review-toolkit/ort) that has functional tests that require a specific environment to run.

Some dependencies like a database are bootstrapped when running tests.
Unfortunately this is not possible for all dependencies.

For the production version of the application a docker image is built that sets up the environment.

Is it possible to use e.g. [IntelliJ's run targets](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/01/run-targets-run-and-debug-your-app-in-the-desired-environment/) to also run the functional tests within this docker environment?
Trying to run it using the mostly default settings (see screenshot below) results in `Connection refused`.

[image: docker run target]

Comment: Running from CLI works by starting the container, copying the sources to the container and running the gradle command:
`docker run --name ort-dev -d ort-dev && docker cp . ort-dev:"/root" && docker exec -it ort-dev /bin/bash -c 'cd /root && ./gradlew :analyzer:funTest --tests "org.ossreviewtoolkit.analyzer.managers.DotNetFunTest"'; docker stop ort-dev`. It would still be awesome if this could be achieved from within IntelliJ.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but there could be an IDE bug, similar to [IDEA-269184](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-269184). Please file a new [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA&c=Subsystem%20Build.%20Gradle) issue with [IDE debug logs](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-269184#focus=Comments-27-4893257.0-0) attached after reproducing.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, I don't even have the "Run on" option despite having the Docker plugin installed (*Edit:* Turns out the "Run on" option is only available in the Ultimate Edition of IntelliJ). So I was looking into an alternative way: Instead of configuring a Gradle task to run on Docker, you can create a Docker run configuration to execute a Gradle task like so:

[image]

Comment: Note to myself: Semi-related is [Debugging an Application Running in Docker With IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.baeldung.com/docker-debug-app-with-intellij).